# prove $ab\in A$, if $A=\{x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz\mid x,y,z\in \mathbb Z\}$, $a,b\in A$

Tags: number-theory

> let $A=\{x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz\mid x,y,z\in \mathbb {Z}\}$, prove that:
>
> if $a,b\in A$, then  $ab\in A$,

I think we must find $A,B,C$ such
$$A^3+B^3+C^3-3ABC=(a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc)(x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz)$$
where $A,B,C,a,b,c,x,y,z\in \mathbb Z$, but I can't find it.

I think this result is interesting, I hope someone can solve it.

Thank you

Answer (score 11):

Hint :
Consider the matrix :
$$\mathcal{D}_{a,b,c}=\begin{pmatrix}
a&b&c\\
c&a&b\\
b&c&a\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
See, $$\mathcal{D}_{a,b,c}\times \mathcal{D}_{x,y,z}=\mathcal{D}_{p,q,r}$$
Now $\det (\mathcal{D}_{a,b,c})=a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$

Looks like this hint solved the problem almost. :P

Comment: How can you find this? can you explain? Thank you

Comment: The determinant is very well-known, I found this from memory. And multiplying these two matrices is not too hard, just tedious, which I give you as exercise. Now multiplying matrices of the type given yields another matrix of the same type. And each such matrix corresponds to an element of $A$ and taking determinant we get the $A,B,C$ you ask for. Is this explanation making it clear?

Comment: Sure, happy to help. A nice problem btw :)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is contained in the other, but by symmetry it is natural to write

$$A=ax+by+cz$$
$$B=cx+ay+bz$$
$$C=bx+cy+az$$ and its easy to see this satisfies the equation given by OP.